# Организация системы тегов

Tags: теги, php, mysql

Всем привет. Поступил заказ, по сути сводится к банальной сети статей с поиском **только** по тегам. Загвоздка в том, что обещают over 9000 посещений и несколько миллионов записей, в связи с чем запрос вида

```
SELECT [...] WHERE tags LIKE %tag1*tag2%
```

кажется неприемлемым. Пока мысли только о создании таблицы тегов с ID и таблицы с перекрестными ссылками[tagID,articleID], но тут боюсь упереться в объем последней - запись может иметь несколько десятков, а то и сотен, характеристик-тегов. Также учесть последовательный поиск (клик-просмотр-клик-просмотр и т.п.)

Собственно, кто что может посоветовать?
// да, на хэшкоде похожая система - представьте десяток миллионов вопросов с 30-200 тегами в каждом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

видимо так: 
хранить теги в отдельной таблице точно также, как и для небольшого сайта.
а на сайт выводить не real-time запросами, а подготовить сперва.
пересчитывать кэш этот можно только при добавлении статьи.
добавляем статью и пересчитываем только те теги, которые в ней.

Comment: О как. Т.е. я правильно понял: создать таблицу [tagID, articleID__S__] и при изменении тегов обновлять ее? А потом пользователю выдавать пересекающиеся значения. Нагрузка больше на админку, но тут она и не страшна. Логично, пока послушаю еще, но похоже на "зачет", спасибо =)

Comment: при таком подходе есть проблемы. например, статья добавилась, а теги не пересчитались. или при удалении статьи не пересчитались.
желательно регулярно(например, раз в сутки) делать полный пересчет.
то есть иногда на сайте будут не совсем точные данные. но это не страшно.

Comment: если взять к примеру сайт avito.ru. там при добавлении объявления, даже когда уже модератор его утвердит, оно не сразу появляется в списке объявлений. у них раз в 5-10 минут происходит индексация. при удалении точно также, объявление не сразу исчезает.
таким образом работают индексирующие серверы (sphinx например). 
Я лично применял Sphinx для поиска, думаю, что и для поиска по тегам его можно применить.

Comment: сомневаюсь, что кто-то вам предложит real-time запрос, который будет работать быстро. так что в любом случае копать в сторону кэша/индекса. либо самому его организовывать, либо пользоваться специальными программами. http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/30594/
да, поисковые движки - это не обязательно поиск по тексту. Они могут работать и по ключам. дельта-индекс тоже не забыть.